# Games using cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, android-ndk, cocos2d-android

I am thinking of developing games in android using cocos2d-android in Java. But i want to develop games which will be cross-platform means they will also work for iPhone OS,etc. 
I read that cocos2d-android api's have been derived from cocos2d-iPhone api.

I am familiar with C++ too.

Can anyone suggest some tools?
Any Suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) is exactly what you want to use for developing games.

> cocos2d-x is an open-source, C++ based, mobile 2D game engine, released under the MIT License . It aims to be multi-platform, lightweight, and developer-friendly, and is a child of the famous "cocos2d-iphone" project, doing its best to keep the primary features sync with it.

It works with Android NDK, iOS, Win32, airplaysdk(marmalade) and etc.

Comment: Ok. I am not that well-versed with C++ but good with Java hence, i was trying to find something which will suit my taste like cocos2D-android.